# Lost organization after disconnecting it from Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I disconnected my organization from Azure Active Directory and now it's missing from both my Microsoft account and this AAD.
It also didn't appear in recently deleted organizations.

It is still existing somewhere because I cannot create organization with the same name.

Before disconnecting it I double-checked that I am the owner of organization and it should remain on my account.

Answer (score 1):

> Lost organization after disconnecting it from Azure Active Directory

I had the same issue once, that was because I did not meet the prerequisites for disconnecting from AAD.

You could check if you meet the prerequisites for disconnecting from AAD based on this document:

[Disconnect your organization from Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/disconnect-organization-from-azure-ad?view=azure-devops)

- Before you disconnect your organization from your directory, make
  sure to **change the organization Owner to a Microsoft account and not
  to a school or work account**. You can't sign in to your organization
  unless your work or school account has the same email address as your
  Microsoft account.
- Add your Microsoft account to the Project Collection Administrator
  group in Organization Settings and confirm that you have Global
  Administrator Permissions in your Azure AD for your Microsoft
  account. You need both because Azure AD users can't disconnect
  organizations from directories. You can add Microsoft accounts to a
  directory as external users.

As workaround, please try to access `https://aex.dev.azure.com/` and change domain to see if your organization lists here:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I completed all this steps before disconnecting. Anyway organization is missing and not event listed as deleted [here](https://aex.dev.azure.com/)

Comment: @NiJeTi, Thanks your reply. Could you see your organization  after change domain? BTW, if you can make sure you can not see your ORG after change the domain, you could open a support case on the Developer Community and they can help you out.

Comment: I cannot see my organization in any way. Solving problem via support.

Comment: I will write a solution when support help me, but resolution is still in progress.

Comment: anything here, i ran into the same thing today?