# No longer able to see existing projects in Azure Devops after connecting AAD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I was logged in to my AzureDevops account using my hotmail account.I then went to Organization Settings and then connected my Org to Azure AD.
After i logged out and logged in back again with the same account, i don't see anymore my projects which i was working on. I have disconnected my Azure AD and also tried switching directories but i am no longer able to see that particular organization anymore.
Any idea how to fix this or why this happened

Answer (score 0):

Please check below points :

Try logging on to https://.visualstudio.com to see you can see the organization and projects, as stated in ***[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/124486/my-devops-organisation-disappeared-after-linking-t.html).***
Check ***[Troubleshoot connecting to a project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/troubleshoot-connection?view=azure-devops)***

**You may not able to signin or access  your organization unless your work or school account has the same email address as your Microsoft account.**

- Although you can add new work accounts to your organization, they're
  treated as new users.
- If you want to access all your work, including its history, you must
  use the same sign-in addresses that you used before your organization
  was connected to your Azure AD.
- For that Add your Microsoft account as a member to your Azure AD Or
  ask the owner of the organization who has proper permissions to  map
  any disconnected members to their Azure AD identities Or invite them
  as guests into the Azure AD.
- Invited user should use corresponding account, work/school account
  for AAD based, personal account for the other.

So basically the user who makes the connection must confirm the following statements are true.

> - User exists in Azure AD as a member. If the user is an Azure AD    guest, rather than member
> - User must have ***project collection administrator or owner of the    organization***
> - User must also have ***Azure Service Administrator or Coadministrator***   permissions for the Azure subscription that's linked to your   organization in Azure DevOps.
> - User isn't using the Microsoft account identity that matches the    Azure AD identity. For example, if the Microsoft account that users    are currently using is jamalhartnett@fabrikam.com, the Azure AD  identity they'll use after connecting is also jamalhartnett@fabrikam.com. Use a single identity that spans both applications, rather than two separate identities using the same  email.
> - Add your work account as an administrator in your Azure DevOps    organization
> - The AAD tenant should be same as the DevOps tenant to connect &    Transfer the ownership of the organization to your work account.

Please see if you have followed the **Prerequisites** to [Connect organization to Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops&preserve-view=true)

**FAQ:** to be refered

1. [why dont i see my organization in the azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-azure-access?view=azure-devops#why-don-t-i-see-my-organization-in-the-azure-portal-)
2. [why do i have to choose between a work or school account and my personal account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-azure-access?view=azure-devops#q-why-do-i-have-to-choose-between-a-work-or-school-account-and-my-personal-account)
3. [what if we cant use the same sign in addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/access-with-azure-ad?view=azure-devops#q-what-if-we-cant-use-the-same-sign-in-addresses)

> **Note:** No other user than the owner of the organization will be able to see the organization under the “Azure DevOps organizations”
> service in the Azure portal. Also, Azure DevOps does not support
> multiple owners, like Azure services that support Role Based Access
> Control (RBAC) do. An Azure DevOps organization will only have a
> single owner at a time :**[reference](https://medium.com/clusterreply/azure-devops-in-organizations-and-enterprises-65e5efcb53c2#:%7E:text=Azure%20DevOps%20Portal-,But%20be%20aware,-!%20A%20new%20organization)**

Please try to access https://aex.dev.azure.com/ and change domain to see if your organization is present in the list.

Or
You may need to **open a support case** on the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) to help you out or raise a support request through azure portal.

**References:**

1. [Lost organization after disconnecting it from Azure Active Directory-Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62498979/lost-organization-after-disconnecting-it-from-azure-active-directory)
2. [What not to do when Connecting Azure DevOps to
   AzureAD |Josh Corrick |](https://blog.corrick.io/what-not-to-do-when-connecting-azure-devops-to-azuread/)
3. [Restore project - Azure DevOps Services | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/restore-project?view=azure-devops)